# transaction receipt logs are empty Ethereum

Tags: transactions, ethereum

[I have a smart contract call and I am trying to monitor the event, but I got an empty logs of the transaction receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A2nX.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

First: You could check is the transaction ended without error

second: define an event in contract and then wherever you want that log to appear, call it in your functions.

A transaction's receipt is only generated if the transaction ends in success. If the transaction ran out of gas or threw an exception, the receipt will not be generated..

Comment: thank you so much, I find the problem is that the transaction run out of gas, the gas estimation is infinite. The contract runs well on remix, but no work on my private, chain, I don't know why?

Comment: if you have a private chain, contract depends on how you define size blocks. Could you share genesis configuration?

Comment: I use the --testnet but with --nodiscover mod

Comment: Could you copy/paste remix adress with cntract and you truffle-config ?

Comment: Try to set gas:0 y gasprice:0 in truffle-config.

Comment: Actually, my contract works well on the ganache-cli but not work on my geth private net work, I start the geth net work by "eth --identity "EDU" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --datadir data --allow-insecure-unlock --port "30303" --rpcapi "debug,personal,db,eth,net,web3" --testnet --nodiscover  console"

Comment: I have no idea how can it be possible. with the same configuration of truffle but have totally different result. I think the ganache environment should be the same as testnet?

Comment: There are differences between ganache-cli and testnet.

Comment: It could be possible that you copy your truffle config ? The parameters that you set there impact directly in the contract deploy.

Comment: My sample truffle-config..you could see that there are different parameters for each network.

Comment: development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },

Comment: that's the network setup and others remain the default config

Comment: I am using geth to run my private chain, seems none of them works for geth. But thank you anyway. for all your patient and help.

Comment: pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
contract Modify {
    event modified_student(address indexed _from, bytes32 _data);
    event modified_teacher(address indexed _from, bytes32 _data);
    event modified_auth(address indexed _from, bytes32 _data);
    function modify_auth(bytes32 data ) public payable
    {
        emit modified_auth(msg.sender, data);
    }
    function modify_teacher(bytes32 data ) public payable
    {emit modified_teacher(msg.sender, data);
    }
    function modify_student(bytes32 data ) public payable
    {emit modified_student(msg.sender, data);
    }
}